# How to map money value from Postgresql in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I know that money type is not good to use in Postgres, but I can't change it and I need to get this value in Java.

I have already tried to use Double, BigDecimal, String, etc. But all of then I get an error like that

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [xpto] in table [xpto]; found [money (Types#DOUBLE)], but expecting [numeric(19, 2) (Types#NUMERIC)]

I don't know what type I have to declare in my variable. Someone can help me?

Comment: "*but I can't change it*" yes of course you can. Just run an ALTER TABLE.

Comment: No, I can't. Because this database is used for others teams in my company and have no permission to alter it.

Comment: When I try retrive the value as a string, I get this error "found [money (Types#DOUBLE)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]"

Comment: You can cast it to the correct data type in your SELECT statement: `select xpto::numeric, ...` - but you will probably need to use a native query for that. Or create a view that fixes the wrong data type and use that in your application (but I don't know if your obfuscation layer can deal with a view rather than a table)

Comment: The alternative is to use `getString() - but you will probably need to declare your variable as a String to workaround the limitations of the obfuscation layer.

Comment: Can I cast of this way using JPA?

Comment: No idea, I don't use obfuscation layers.